# In the context of machine learning are there any specific specs one can evaluate to determine if one video card is more appropriate than another?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, clock

There are many different specifications provided when comparing GPUs. For instance, some of the many specifications include items like:

- Single precision floating point “theoretical” computation.
- Memory clock.
- Core clock.

So, what are the most relevant specs to compare when looking at GPU use for machine learning purposes?

Comment: There’s nothing “stupid” about this question but it is too broad, open ended and you are asking us for shipping advice and that is not what this site is about. You are asking for shopping advice and asking us to try to determine what is “best” when that is a subjective idea. You also ask, “Since machine learning on GPUs is taking off, it would be helpful to have a framework on how to understand the capabilities of these cards for these purposes” That is massively too broad. Sorry, but another forum—one that is more conversational and open-end—might be the best place for a question like this.

Comment: thanks @JakeGould, I will try to make the question's focus more narrow, and if not possible I will delete. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Okay, sometimes I am cynical about someone saying they can edit down a huge question into a more focused and appropriate one. You really did a great job on this! +1. I went ahead and edited a bit more for clarity as well and flagged this to be reopened.

Comment: Thanks @JakeGould It couldn't have happened without your input!